# Facebook tab renamed itself. Can't change

Tags: facebook

Had a facebook tab called "Sign Up" as a gateway into an iframe canvas page. Nothing shocking. This last round of updates have moved the "tabs" to the left side of fb pages. For some reason, my tab, named "Sign Up" and still named so in the application settings, renamed itself to "Hello" when they updated the new look. I have no idea where this is coming from, but the client is now freaking out and Googling for this answer has been totally fruitless. Does anyone know why this would be happening? I tried resaving the application settings to no avail.

There's no code to post. There's some static HTML and CSS. Here's a screenshot of the app page:

[image]

As you can see it says "Hello" for reasons I cannot figure out. In the application settings I was able to change the icon from the default. As you can see here, the tab name is "Sign Up"

[image]

Nowhere in the settings is there the word "Hello". As stated I was able to add an icon.

Comment: Maybe you need to post some code and describe in more detail what you are trying to do. I don't think you will get much help if you don't post any code or examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is just a FB bug when you switch over to the new page format, but I did figure out how to fix it. If you encounter this problem go to your page and click the "Edit Page" button in the top right. You'll end up here:

[image]

Go to the apps tab and click "Edit Settings" under the app name. The popup shown above will appear. Just click "remove" and then click "Edit Settings" again and click "add". Your tab will now respect the name you have given it. Annoying.

Comment: FYI, this applies EVERY TIME you want to rename your tab. The client wanted it to say "Sign Up FREE" after I had changed it to "Sign Up" and I had to use the same method.